# CakePHP output a select input for picking a value from a joined table

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I have managed to join 2 of my tables `clients` and `risk_codes` to each other where `clients.risk_code_id` is a foreign key `for risk_codes.id`.

In my edit view for Clients I ouput a form using the HTML Helper. E.g. to add an input to edit `clients.name` I would use `echo $this->Form->input('name');`

Given that `risk_codes` is a separate table/model how would I output a select dropdown with the options being `risk_codes.name` and the values being `risk_codes.id`?

The tables are linked like so:

```
Client belongsTo RiskCode
RiskCode hasMany Client
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `RiskCode` model make sure that [`displayField`](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/model-attributes.html#displayfield) is either set to `null` or `name` (the latter is one of the defaults):

```
public $displayField = 'name'; // or null;
```

In the controller set a [list](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#find-list) of risk codes for the view:

```
$this->set('riskCodes', $this->Client->RiskCode->find('list'));
```

And in the view simply reference the appropriate foreign key field name:

```
echo $this->Form->input('risk_code_id');
```

CakePHP will automatically create an appropriate select list, using the models `id` and `displayField` field values from the list set as `riskCodes`.

ps. Many questions like this are answered in the [Cookbook](http://book.cakephp.org/), and can also be figured out by using CakePHP to [bake](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/console-and-shells/code-generation-with-bake.html) the controllers and views.